# “Save and Continue Edit” button is not working if it is creating quote

Tags: magento-1.8, module, admin

Why Cant I click [image]

if im creating a new Quote, but if the will edit the save quote, it will be functional. Here is my file code.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'quotation';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quotation';

    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Save Quote'));
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Delete Quote'));

    $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save && Continue Edit'),
        'onclick'   => 'saveandcon()',
        'class'     => 'save',
    ), -100);


    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function toggleEditor() {
            if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('quotation_content') == null) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            } else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            }
        }

        function saveandcon(){
            var edit_form = " . $this->getRequest()->getParam("id") . ";
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/1/');
        }

public function getHeaderText()
{
    if( Mage::registry('quotation_data') && Mage::registry('quotation_data')->getId() ) {
        return Mage::helper('quotation')->__("Edit Sales Quote '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('quotation_data')->getQuoteNumber()));
    } else {
        return Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Create new Sales Quotation');
    }
}
```

Now what should I need to do it properly.

Here is my controller file.

```
public function saveAction() {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $qbill = $this->getRequest()->getPost('bill_street');
    $qship = $this->getRequest()->getPost('ship_street');
    $qnote = $this->getRequest()->getPost('salesquotenotes');
    $groupid = $this->getRequest()->getPost('quote_custgroupid');
    $storeid = $this->getRequest()->getPost('quote_store_id');

    if ($data) {

        $model = Mage::getModel('quotation/quotation');
        $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        $model->setBillStreet($qbill[0] . ' ' . ($qbill[1] ? $qbill[1] : '') );
        $model->setShipStreet($qship[0] . ' ' . ($qship[1] ? $qship[1] : '') );
        $model->setQuoteNotes($qnote);
        $model->setQuoteCustgroupid($groupid);
        $model->setQuoteStoreId($storeid);

        try {
            /*if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                    $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                            ->setUpdateTime(now());
            } else {
                    $model->setUpdateTime(now());
            }*/

            $c = $this->getRequest()->getPost('add_product');
            $productsToAdd = $this->_decodeInput($c);

            foreach($productsToAdd as $key => $value)
            {
                $product_id = $key;

                $product = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

                $quotationItem = Mage::getModel('quotation/quotation_items');
                $quotationItem->setQuotationId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
                $quotationItem->setItemId($product_id);
                $quotationItem->setSku($product->getSku());
                $quotationItem->setName($product->getName());
                $quotationItem->setQty(1);
                if ($product->getSpecialPrice() > 0) {
                    $quotationItem->setUnitPrice($product->getSpecialPrice());
                }
                else {
                    $quotationItem->setUnitPrice($product->getPrice());
                }
                $quotationItem->setWeight($product->getWeight());
                $quotationItem->setTaxClassId($product->getTaxClassId());
                $model->addItem($quotationItem);
            }

            $model->save();

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            else {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Quotation was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Here is my form.php

```
protected function _prepareForm()


{
  $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                  'id' => 'edit_form',
                                  'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                  'method' => 'post',
                                  'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                               )
  );
  $form->setUseContainer(true);
  $this->setForm($form);
  return parent::_prepareForm();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines in your admin block constructor.

```
$this->_formScripts[] = " function saveandcon(){
        editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
    }
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `_construct` function

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'quotation';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quotation';

    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Save Quote'));
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Delete Quote'));

    $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save && Continue Edit'),
        'onclick'   => 'saveandcon()',
        'class'     => 'save',
    ), -100);


    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function toggleEditor() {
            if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('quotation_content') == null) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            } else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'quotation_content');
            }
        }

        function saveandcon(){
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }
";
}
```

Comment: still not working sir.

Comment: i already updated the _construct function.. but still if i create a quote, i can only save but cannot save&continueEdit